# LuaLaTeX Beamer notes, and Hebrew as Babel main language causes invisible notes

Tags: beamer, luatex, hebrew, bidi

@UlrikeFischer
@JavierBezos

When I add the word `"main"` to babel's language preference, notes become invisible.

MWE1 - Without the word `"main"`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=en-GB]{english}
%
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Lorem}Ipsum}
\note{Comment}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE1]

MWE2 - With the word `"main"`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=en-GB]{english}
%
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Lorem}Ipsum}
\note{Comment}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]